# Target client option in setting up a queue on WAS

Tags: jms, websphere, ibm-mq

In WAS console, on the Queues page, there is an option called 'Target Client' and the options are MQ and JMS.  Now MQ i understand is websphere MQ, but what is JMS? Any JMS provider other than Websphere MQ? Because in my case the target is actually websphere MQ but i have selected JMS here and it still works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Target client defines how the message will intepreted by the receiving application.
If you choose MQ, then a RFH2 header will be added with MQ specific info otherwise JMS info will be added (jms_bytes, jms_text etc..).

[IBM has some info about it](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm10910_.htm)